# Most Efficient Way of Exploding a Pyspark Dataframe Column

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a very big pyspark dataframe. The dataframe contains two important columns: A key and tokens related to that key. So each row has a key and a list of tokens:

```
load_df.show(5)

+--------------------+-----------+ 
|       token        |    key    | 
+--------------------+-----------+
|[-LU4KeI8o, FrWx6...|   h9-1256 |
|[]                  |   h1-2112 |
|[HDOksdh_vv, aIHD...|   e3-0139 |
|[-LU4KeI8o, FrWx6...|   S3-4156 |
+--------------------+-----------+
```

Now, I want to count the number of times each token appeared relative to different keys. But the problem is whatever I do turn to be very slow.
I want to know what is the best way to this?

I have tried to explode the token column and then count.

Something like this:

```
explode_df = load_df.withColumn('token', F.explode('token'))

load_freq = explode_df.groupby('token')\
                    .count()\
                    .sort('count', ascending=False)
```

or this:

```
explode_df = load_df.withColumn('token', F.explode('token'))

load_freq = explode_df.groupby('token')\
                    .agg(F.collect_set('key'), F.count(F.col('key')).alias('count'))\
                    .sort('count', ascending=True)
```

The dataframe has more than 250 million rows and this method is very slow. I wonder if there is a better way to reach the same result faster and more efficient.

Comment: i think what you have might be the best..do you absolutely need a sort step here?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala I think I need it, as I want to work on certain quantile of the data. maybe I can sort them separately, but I don't think it would be much faster.

Comment: Shouldn't you be grouping by both key and token here? After you explode you can try partitioning it by key and token and writing it to parquet then read it back and do the aggregation but the improvement would be marginal if any I would suspect